# Can't start LibGDX Tool 2D Particle Editor

Tags: java, jar, nullpointerexception, libgdx, particles

Please, help me.
I downloaded jar file from https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/tools.html
It is runnable-2D-particles.jar
When I run it, opened the program unusable. Nope field rendering, and all the blocks are empty.

Log in console:

```
C:\Users\matha>java -jar C:\runnable-2D-particles.jar
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.createDisplayPixelFormat(LwjglGraphics.java:320)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setupDisplay(LwjglGraphics.java:214)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglCanvas.create(LwjglCanvas.java:190)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglCanvas$1.addNotify(LwjglCanvas.java:90)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.show(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.tools.particleeditor.ParticleEditor.<init>(ParticleEditor.java:92)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.tools.particleeditor.ParticleEditor$6.run(ParticleEditor.java:532)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

P.S. Video-driver installed.
How can I fix this problem?
I use WIN10, jdk1.8.0_51, jre1.8.0_60 (if it important fact)

Comment: how do you launch it? Just tested on my machine with WIN10 and that jar works just great.

Comment: @Enigo I launch it by double click and by console. Same result in both variants.

Comment: well, it seems that the problem is with OpenGL, because `at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.createDisplayPixelFormat(LwjglGraphics.java:320)` line 320 in `LwjglGraphics` says `OpenGL is not supported by the video driver`. So you should update your video card drivers.

Comment: @Enigo so, what can I do with this?

Comment: Check that your card supports at least OpenGL 1.5, and if so update your video card drivers.

Comment: @Enigo I think, that I must use another machine, because I already updated drivers. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with OpenGL, because at `com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.createDisplayPixelFormat(LwjglGrap‌​hics.java:320)` line 320 in `LwjglGraphics` says `OpenGL is not supported by the video driver`. 
So you should check that your card supports at least OpenGL 1.5, and if so update your video card drivers.